# How to invoke child component function from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field component that meets these conditions:

Upon first focus, nothing happens until the field is valid, then a valid class is applied

Upon first blur, if the field is invalid, apply an invalid class.

After the first blur, upon any further engagement with the field, a class is applied whenever the value of the field changes from valid to invalid or vice versa.

To achieve this I have done this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      touched: false,
      valid: false,
      focused: false,
      value: ""
    };

    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFocus() {}

  handleBlur() {
    if (!this.state.touched) {
      this.setState({
        touched: true
      });
    } else if (this.state.touched) {
      this.setState({
        focused: true
      });
    }
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const val = e.target.value

    this.setState({ value: val }, () => {
        this.validateField();
      }
    );
  }

  validateField() {
    const touched = this.state.touched;
    const focused = this.state.focused;
    const valid = this.state.valid;
    const value = this.state.value;

    if (value.length >= 5) {
      this.setState({
        valid: true,
        touched: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ valid: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          id={this.props.id}
          name={this.props.name}
          type="text"
          className={`form-control ${styles["kyi-input"]} ${
            this.state.valid ? "is-valid" : ""
          } ${this.state.touched && !this.state.valid ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
          required
          spellCheck="false"
          autoComplete="off"
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.value}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {

    handleInput(val, name) {
        // Can get value of input here
        this.setState({
          [name]: val
        });
    }

    render() {
        <Input placeholder="Test" onChange={(val) => {this.handleInput(val, 'inputName')}}/>    
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

It works, but this means that the state of the field lives in the child component and not the parent.

The input field's onBlur function is reliant on the state of the field.

Is there a way to refactor this so that the input state lives in the parent component while the onBlur function lives in the child component?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should get all your State in the Parent component, you should also get all the functions that modify it in the Parent Component. This would allow you to have a 'single source of truth' that keeps track of state's changes and pass it to all your child components.
Check out [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: That is exactly what I’m trying to achieve (having the state in the parent component) except I want to keep specifically only the onBlur function in the child component to avoid unnecessary repetition.

Comment: The onBlur method modifies the state of your component, as a result, this method has to live inside the stateful component (Parent component in this case if you move all state inside of it), and has to be passed on to the child component . You could keep your method inside the Input components but this component has to have it's own state. I don't see how you could modify the parent's state with a method living inside a child component.

Comment: It's not the parent's state that I'm trying to modify. I'm trying to have the parent state communicate its state to a function within the child component:

Whenever the value of the Input field (which is a state in the parent component) changes, it invokes a function in the child component that checks the value of the input and acts accordingly.

Comment: That's fine, you can pass state as props to your child component, you can have your function do whatever it wants inside the child component, but it would'nt be able to modify the parent's state.